# Meteor Hero / Heroku. Unsuccessful deployment. Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later. code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor

Failed at deploying https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/meteor-application-template-react . Application logs state Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later and code=H10 desc="App crashed". Any suggestions to resolve this?

Followed https://github.com/jkrup/meteor-hero. Cloned and attempted to deploy https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/meteor-application-template-react using meteor-hero. Current node version is v12.18.0. The following is from the application logs:

```
2020-06-29T22:56:04.080782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2020-06-29T22:56:07.325000+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-29T22:56:07.389731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-29T22:56:07.392546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-29T22:56:07.252302+00:00 app[web.1]: Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later.
2020-06-29T22:56:27.232897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2020-06-29T22:56:30.150010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-29T22:56:30.194140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-29T22:56:30.095715+00:00 app[web.1]: Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later.
2020-06-29T23:17:03.889869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-29T23:17:23.852420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2020-06-29T23:17:27.017113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-29T23:17:27.060048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-29T23:17:26.946026+00:00 app[web.1]: Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later.
2020-06-29T23:20:50.586056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-bayou-21702.herokuapp.com request_id=a3a2e5bb-604a-4a1c-a217-631c96d0bd6d fwd="204.210.114.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-29T23:20:51.021127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-bayou-21702.herokuapp.com request_id=65c6c08f-337b-4493-876e-7e8d7579b045 fwd="204.210.114.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-29T23:21:11.056284+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-bayou-21702.herokuapp.com request_id=e0751fb3-dc82-479a-b05c-bbc13622b179 fwd="204.210.114.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-29T23:21:11.312540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-bayou-21702.herokuapp.com request_id=8d32ae23-ba5c-4be4-b55b-45d1a65b10bb fwd="204.210.114.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any suggestions to resolve this problem?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Did you find a solution in the meantime? The docs says that if you deploy in a node environment, you can specify the node version https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version - but how can I do this when I use meteor-hero?

Comment: Ah, it seems that the node version is hardcoded ... https://github.com/jkrup/meteor-hero/pull/5

Answer (score 0):

As long as [this pull request](https://github.com/jkrup/meteor-hero/pull/5) is not merged, you have to manually edit you dockerfils.js - see https://github.com/jkrup/meteor-hero/pull/5/files